# Accidental Whatsapp privacy breach

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, privacy, chat-history

I exported my chat history with my friend, JJ, to my Google drive. Somehow a chat history between JJ and someone else (Meg) was exported. I have no idea who Meg is and i have no record of her in Whatsapp or anywhere on my phone.
I tried again and my chat with JJ was exported and saved. However,it did export Meg's a few more times as well.
It seems very wrong that i have a stranger's chat history with my friend saved on my drive.
Any ideas how this happened? I'm on Samsung Note 8.